# How to ssh into win10 using an azure user (an Azure AD domain user)? is there a "correct way" to write this user on the ssh command?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, azure, user

I already installed the optional OpenSSH client and server,
I made it a service,
but I cant log in.

I have done this same steps on three laptops, two of them work at the first try, last one didn't. The only difference is that the other laptops use a local user while the third uses azure users (I need ssh on those users, not a new one).

I think it has to be with what's the correct way to input the username on ssh.

```
C:\Users\PabloFuenzalida>whoami
azuread\pablofuenzalida

C:\Users\PabloFuenzalida>net users

User accouns from \\
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrador            DefaultAccount           Invitado
WDAGUtilityAccount
Command was completed with one or more errors.
```

net users command tells me there was an error executing the command

I have tryed those combinatios, none of them seems to recognize the password (I already checked the password)
pablofuenzalida@192.168.1.150
PabloFuenzalida@192.168.1.150
azuread\pablofuenzalida@192.168.1.150

ps: I do am prompted to write a password, so the ssh service is working

Comment: By an Azure user you mean a user that is connected to an Azure AD domain? Be sure you [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.  Additionally, all error messages should be in English.

Comment: 1) yes, I mean an user that is connected to an Azure AD domain. 2) I'll edit the question 3) I'll change the error messages to english, I didn't do at first because I don´t know the exact syntax of the error message in english. 4) thanks for taking your time to give me feedback

Comment: Try “username@domain”@server_name

Comment: I was trying to do something similar (actually connecting to a Windows laptop running OpenSSH whose user account is managed in AzureAD), and the form that was accepted was `ssh "azuread\username"@machinename`. Unfortunately, having seen `sshd: Accepted publickey` in the logs, nothing happened - there was no response, and the connection timed out with `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSH on windows [currently doesn't support AAD user login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration).

See [this github issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1787).

An alternative solution to use this [workaround](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1476#issuecomment-642974745) which support password authentication only, or, if your company policy allows, create a local user in order to use key-based authentication.

Comment: too bad :c I ended up using teamviewer at the end as workarround. from that computer I can SSH all others and work from there. Thank you for taking the time